# Plot is away from axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot this graph and I see the plot is a bit away from the axis.

[image: Ammonium bar plot]

This is the code I am using.

```
(
    df3[["AA", "NH4+ (5D)", "NH4+ (14D)"]]
    .set_index("AA")
    .plot(kind="bar", yerr=[df3["STDV NH4+"], df3["STDV NH4+.1"]],
         figsize=(18, 6))
)
plt.savefig("NH4+_stdv.jpg", dpi=300)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using pandas, not seaborn to plot. If you capture the `Axes` object (call it `ax`) returned by the plotting command, you can do:

```py
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
```

to remove the margin from the y-axis